# Countable class of real-valued differentiable functions with different derivatives at a point must differ in a neighborhood.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Consider the following statement.

> Consider a class of functions $\mathcal{F}=\{f_1,\ldots,f_N\}$ such
> that $f_{n}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable for
> all $n=1,\ldots, N$. If there exists a point $x^{*} \in \mathbb{R}$
> such that $f_{1}^{\prime}\left(x^{*}\right) \neq f_{n}^{\prime}\left(x^{*}\right)$ and $f_{1}\left(x^{*}\right) = f_{n}\left(x^{*}\right)$ for $n>1$, then there exists
> $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $f_{1}(x) \neq f_{n}(x)$ for all $x \in (x^*,x^*+\varepsilon)$ and $n>1$.

The above statement is true when $N$ is a finite number, I wonder if we can extend this statement to the case where $\mathcal{F}$ is an infinite set of functions. To do so, we need extra assumptions because $f_1(x)=x$ and $f_n(x)=n x^2$ is a counterexample. What extra assumptions would need to be added to turn this into a true statement?